# Better logging from pub/sub Cloud Function in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to improve the logging I get from my node.js based GCP Pub/Sub Cloud Functions.  Using only `console.log` I can see everything in Stackdriver but the logs aren't very readable.  Stacktraces get split across multiple lines and log levels are mostly ignored (so everything is either debug or error, and nothing inbetween).

I tried using Google Logging Library (via @google-cloud/logging-bunyan), which fixes the above problems but introduces more (serious) problems.

When using `@google-cloud/logging-bunyan` with a poorly behaving function (that crashes), you get little or no logs in Stackdriver.  The problem is the asynchronous nature of the library and that the function doesn't allow things to be logged after it has crashed.  I tried opening and closing the logger and the start and end of every function which did improve things a bit.  But I started getting some very strange errors from it (such as `Maximum call stack size exceeded`).

I gave up in the end and reverted back to console.log.

Note, that the `@google-cloud/logging-bunyan` solution seems to work well with HTTP Cloud Functions.  I use an exit-hook to flush the logger in case of a crash and so far haven't seen any problems with it.

Comment: generally you could use pub/sub for logging purposes, assuming some database where to collect those logs.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your post to ask a question. It is unclear what information you are seeking.

Comment: Any chance you've tried Winston to see if the same errors happen with that library? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/logging-winston